# Multinomial logit with multiple and possibly correlated choices

Tags: regression, multinomial-distribution, logit

I am working with a data set of the following kind:

> ```
>  firmid tranchetype nolenders  TA
>       1      Senior         5 100  
>       1      Senior         6 100  
>       1   Mezzanine         2 100  
>       2      Senior         1 340  
>       2    Revolver         3 340
> ```

Tranches are the choices the firms make to structure their debt (e.g. the first three tranches relate to firm 1). The variable nolenders (number of lenders) is tranche-specific, while TA (total assets) is firm specific.

I am interested in modeling these choices controlling for the effects of the tranche- and firm-specific covariates. From what I understand multinomial logit (MNL) is a way to go. However, there are several considerations/questions which I would like to clarify:

1. Firms can make arbitrary many choices of tranche types. My recollection is that in the MNL models only once choice is allowed per observation. Are there some extensions of these models which are suitable to this kind of data?
2. I suspect that there is some positive association between the choices within the firms. At first glance, firm fixed effects can deal with this, but this would result in using about 4k firm dummies (total number of firms) over about 12k observations (total number of tranches). Is this practice acceptable from the statistical viewpoint? What could be the alternative ways to deal with this "within-correlation"?

Thank you very much in advance for the help and references.
Yan